# C potential memory leak malloc

Tags: c, opencv, memory-leaks

The following is a code that inserts in a hashtable (obviously) developed in the openCV contrib branch. I suspect there is a memory leak in the code. The reason I suspect that is that I read the hashtable from a file ~200 MB in size and when I check the memory consumed by the program when it runs in a matter of seconds it exceeds 1GB, and if I let it run for some time the entire operating system crashes as it exceeds 6 GB.

I know a bit about C, but I want to make sure that this is the case. If there is a memory leak how can I fix it?

```
int hashtableInsert(hashtable_int *hashtbl, KeyType key, void *data){    
    struct hashnode_i *node;
    size_t hash=hashtbl->hashfunc(key)%hashtbl->size;

    node=(hashnode_i*)malloc(sizeof(struct hashnode_i));

    if (!node)
        return -1;
    node->key=key;

    node->data=data;
    node->next=hashtbl->nodes[hash];
    hashtbl->nodes[hash]=node;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't see memory leak..

Comment: Why dou you suppose there is a memory leak? Because there's a `malloc` but no `free`? The `free` is done when you destroy the hash table. As long as you work with the hash table, the memory for the nodes must stay allocated.

Comment: I read the hashtable from a file ~200 MB and when I check the memory consumed by the program when this runs in a matter of seconds it exceeds 1GB

Comment: And if I let it run for some time the entire operating system crashes as it exceeds 6 GB

Comment: A memory leak is when you program go back to a state consuming more memory even if all tasks it run before are over. Just consuming to much memory is not a leak.

Comment: That's not necessarily a memory leak. It may merely be a poor design that requires a lot of memory. But that's hard to tell without knowing what the data and key tapes are and whether the hash table also deletes nodes during the lifetime of the program.

Comment: Thanks please put this as a solution, as I only wanted to check if there is a potential memory leak in the piece of code. And mention explicitly that it has no memory leak.

Comment: Number of `malloc()` calls: `1`; number of `free()` calls: `0`. So **yes**! This function reserves memory it does not release (but my guess is that the responsability to release the memory is elsewhere in the code ... so **no**; there probably is no memory leak in the whole program).

Comment: The code seems fishy: `node->next=hashtbl->nodes[hash];
    hashtbl->nodes[hash]=node;` How exactly does this make any sense? You set your new node's next to point at a node x. Then you overwrite node x, including it's next pointer, with the new node. Without knowing the greater context, this seems like complete nonsense code to me.

Comment: @Lundin: It inserts a new node at the head of a linked list for bucket `hash`: The new node is the new head; its `next` points to the old head. Each bucket in the hash table is the head of a linked list.

Comment: yes @Lundin that's how I understood it, just inserting the new node as the head

Comment: C and C++ are different languages! Don't add C++ tag for C question!

Comment: @pmg my question was regarding this exact function if there is a dangling pointer or an orphan pointer or something else that I might be missing. Memory allocation isn't considered a leak! and yes you're right about your assumption.

Comment: @Olaf I assumed people developing with C++ most probably have good knowledge of C and memory layouts as well. But sorry my bad!

Comment: If thery have, they also follow the C tag.

Comment: the code you show seems not to have any memory leak although it is a bit difficult to tell from the lack of info e.g. how a hashnode looks like or how large the hashtable is, does the hashtable grow etc.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't spot the memory leak (if there is one), but of course you can use the memory leak checker [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/). You run it during runtime.

If you cannot understand how to use it from the link I mentioned, do this:

> Let's take your program, as `hash.c`. Got to the command line and compile it, for eg :
>
> ```
> gcc hash.c -Wall
> ```
>
> If your program compiles successfully, an executable or `out` file will appear. As we have not specified the name of the executable, it's default name will be `a.out`. So let's run it with [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/):
>
> ```
> valgrind -- leak-check=full ./a.out
> ```
>
> This will run executable, along with valgrind, and if there is a memory leak, it will show it when the executable ends.
>
> ---
>
> If you do not have [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) installed, you can install it from [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.install.html).